# jquery tabs reload

Tags: jquery, tabs, reload

I am trying to figure out how to load the tabs the way I want. Basically when someone visits my page I want it to create 2 tabs(which I have working). Now inside of each of those tabs I have a widget that is put there through embed code (which is working fine). However, when I switch from one tab to another it is reloading the data in each tab. So say I was watching a video in one when I switch to the other one it stops the video and when I go back it restarts it. Is there any way to stop it from reloading the tabs once they are loaded? I tried setting cache to true but it didnt seem to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone at all no how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the cache option on the tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cache.

Set it to true and it won't reload the tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that content in  or  tags is reloaded by the browser whenever it is hidden.

You can also see that to get embedded objects to change you need to rewrite the HTML for it, simply changing the src attribute will not cut it.